# Swatches от Woodmart работают не для всех товаров Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Не могу понять в чем проблема, для одного товара всё ок, для другого ломается.
Вот на первой картинке выбираешь цвет, но его название не отображается, также нельзя в галерее снизу перейти к какой-то картинке, Причем это для всей категории товаров так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На другом же товаре всё ок, можно и выбрать картинку и цвет правильно ставится с его названием.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть причина, уже 2 карточки между собой сравнивал, всё задается одинаково.

Comment: Напишите им в поддержку либо на support forum.

Comment: Не могу размещать топики без кода лицензии, которой у меня нет.

Comment: Ну, по картинкам мы Вам вряд ли поможем как-то. Если это тема приобретенная клиентом, то запросите код у клиента, если это nullable тема, то в принципе ничего хорошего Вас не ждет.